# how can i update existing database of my android app on every device?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

this app has many features but one is this ,the student can search his desired book ,and the app will then show him where this book is ,which row which shelf ..author name ,tag number ..
if new books arrived to library how i can update the existing database which will be on every phone ,
can i send the updated database how it will be possible ?
or can i send new sql queries how that will be possible ?
or any suggestion from you ?
the app is offline i dont want it to use internet every time ,just for updation only once in a week.

Comment: use the Alarmmanager to requesting the server in the week interval, and while the new books added in the server just maintain timestamp when it is being added, when the client app hits the server that time just check by the time stamp( ie, before one week records) and send the JSON response the client.

Comment: can you share some usefull links i am new to android ,just learned how to implement database ,the rest i dont know like where to put my new updates or things and how these will get to users etc

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the version number passed in OnCreate method in Database class where you extend SqliteOpen Helper. When new version app is installed it will call OnUpgrade(..) method, here you write all your queries.

Answer (score 1):

First thing u need to update the version of your existing database which is already created in your app.

**This is the brief about**

***onUpgrade()***

```
1. SQLiteOpenHelper should call the super constructor.
2. The onUpgrade() method will only be called when the version integer is larger than the current version running in the app.
3. If you want the onUpgrade() method to be called, you need to increment the version number in your code.
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Rohit Heera , an application upgrade will solve your problem but in my answer i would be answering a different approach.

> if new books arrived to library how i can update the existing
>   database which will be on every phone

When a new book arrive, or you have a collection of books ready for updating the database, then you can plan to send push notification to each device which would let the user know that their are some new books available. 
After that(on clicking the push notification), it would be clients responsibility to hit the server apis and get the new books.

Approach to schedule push notification:

- Weekly push notification
- As an when a new book arrives.
- Whenever a collection(lets say 50) of books arrive.

This way you won't be enforcing user to update the application.

Comment: so far  its good i got the idea but how to do these can you prefer some links ?

Comment: Sending push notification and creating web api depends on the server side technology you are reading.
push on android: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start
Within OnMessageReceive() you can hit the web api and get the data. Upon getting data, add this data to your local database.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a static database and you just want to replace the file on the device. If that is the case try this.

You can zip your new database file and put it in the raw directory.

When the app starts and before you create the connection you need to delete the current database with (make sure you keep track of the database path for later)

```
File existingDb = context.getDatabasePath([name of database]);
if(dbDir.exists()) {
        dbDir.delete();
    }
```

Then unzip the new database file, find the correct file in the zip and copy it to the database directory that you kept track of earlier.

```
ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(context.getResources().openRawResource([zip res]));

try {
        ZipEntry ze = null;
        while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            String fileName = ze.getName();
            // ensure only plists are added to the input streams
            if (DATABASE_FILE_NAME.equals(fileName)) {
                int actual = 0;
                byte[] baf = new byte[MAX_DOWNLOAD_CHUNK];
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File([outDir], fileName));
                while ((actual = zis.read(baf, 0, MAX_DOWNLOAD_CHUNK)) > 0) {
                    out.write(baf, 0, actual);
                }

                out.flush();
                out.close();
                zis.closeEntry();
            }
        }
    } finally {
        try {
            zis.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // file is already closed. ignore
        }
    }
```

You should now be able to connect to the new database as per normal

Comment: i like this idea the most .. because every phone will have the same database static so if new books to be inserted i have to send the whole  database to every user and replace the old one .. but how can i do that ,if the admin update database on pc ,then how it will send to each and every user

Comment: This solution only works when the user updates the app (requires new database to be in apk.
As mentioned it should ideally use one of:
1. push notifcations
2. sync manager
3. Send a request at runtime for any updates on the server.

Obviously these all require more work

Comment: why even my question is on hold ???? if i dont know a thing who will answer me for that ??? who is gonna help me out it was my first ever try over here i am disapointed by their action .. i really needed help with this thing .. thanks guys for your support ..how can i de activate my account ?

Comment: I think it has been put on hold because there is so many opinions on how to solve the question. The only things you can do, is if you have access to a server and are able to implement one of the above mentioned solutions then that is the route I'd go down. If you need a solution that can only be done in the app you'll need the above solution which means the users will need to update their app.